# Can I register a Func factory with type parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I find myself needing to take, in several places, a collection of a given type and create a new instance of a class with that type. The new class already takes a type argument:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public List<T> MyList { get; set; }

    public Foo<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        this.MyList = list;
    }
}
```

My initial thought was that I should set up a factory for this, but then I thought that it could just as easily go into the Autofac module as a Func factory, so I tried the following:

```
builder.Register<Func<List<T>, Foo<T>>>(x => list => new Foo<T>(list));
```

I'm getting errors here because it doesn't know what to do with `T`, I can't make my module take a type argument. Is there a way to make this registration work, or should I just create a `FooFactory<T>` class and be done with it?

Comment: the compiler needs to know what `T` is.

Comment: You're missing a `>` in `builder.Register<Func<List<T>, Foo<T>>(` that's why it tries to invoke `Func<List<T>, Foo<T>>` which cannot be used like a method...

Comment: Edited. I understand that the compiler needs to understand `T`, but I can't make my Autofac module take a type argument. What I need to know is if it's possible to make the compiler know what `T` is inside a binding like this.

Answer (score 3):

*Autofac* has built-in support for collection (including list). See [Implicit Relationship Types from the documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html). The `RegisterGeneric` methods allows the registration of an open type (a generic one).

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Foo<>)).As(typeof(IFoo<>);
builder.RegisterType<Service1>().As<IService>();
builder.RegisterType<Service2>().As<IService>();
```

When *Autofac* will resolve a `IFoo<IService>` it will provide a `List<IService>` with all registered `IService`